# AudioTrack Latency

Tags: voip, android-audiomanager, audiotrack

I'm making an application, that will be capable to make a VOIP communications on WAN, using AudioManager, specifically AudioTrack and AudioRecord, AudioRecord works fine but I have serious problems with the latency to play with AudioTrack. It is really high and unacceptable. I'm receiving chunks of 160Bytes and my audio settings are of 16 bit, 8KHz, 1 Channel, by that, in my chunk of 160 bytes I have about 10 ms by chunk, I will not have significative latency

I know that they are a lot of peoples with the same problem, but VOIP applications exists and probably the problem is mine.

PD: I'm programming in Java, I have tested it between a Motorola Milestone (Droid, android 2.2) and in another Samsung phone (android 2.3) and I have the same problems in both playing device. Also, I have tried to play my sound streamed to my computer and it is in real time. By that, the problem is in the player (AudioTrack). The latency of the network is very low (I'm on WAN) and I receive more than 99% of the packets (about 16Kb/s).

There is any way to continue with a VOIP program and make it usable?

Really thanks, beyond this problem, I haven't found some clear solution and it surely exist. It is a very usual and usefull, more in a communication device.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use UDP instead of TCP? If not, consider Google for "Android UDP example". If yes, sorry for bothering.